# Is there an non-engineer-friendly auto-"convert apk architecture" tool for linux/anbox?

Tags: apk

Non-android entheausist here, just wondering why "convert apk architecture" returned no search results on duckduckgo, as did my search for an x86_64 version of the Kindle.apk...

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? I am confused to what you are interested in as I am not familiar with converting apk architectures

Comment: @GabrielFair I believe the asker wants to have the appropriate APK with native libraries compiled for x86_64, as explain on [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/168320/44325), since running an app with unsupported architecture will potentially crash the app when calling the missing native libs.