# How to know that a installed app is 32bit or 64bit?

Tags: applications

How to know that a installed application on my android is 32bit or 64bit version.

Comment: First of all, originally Android apps were multi-platform, hence all libraries were included for all supported platforms. Nowadays if the developer publishes the app as app-bundle Google only sends those partial APK to your device that match your device platform. Hence if you see an APK file named "armv8" it is 64bit, in case of an armv7[e] it is 32bit.

Comment: Possible dupe of [How to tell what architecture an APK is intended for?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/168302/44325)

Comment: A pure Java app is neither 32bit nor 64bit. If it includes some pre-built native libraries, those are certainly. Extract the libraries from `lib` directory inside APK and use `file` command to check if it's 32bit or 64bit.

Comment: Lets take an example of pubg if I install it from playstore on android 10+ then 64-bit version get installed but if I install it on android 9 then 32 bit get installed. Now if i download it from official site which provide only one apk then how to know which version get installed on my android 10 since both 32 and 64 bit can be installed on android 10.