# How to detect cpu architecture and deliver correct apk?

Tags: adb, installation, apk, scripts, cpu

There are a variety of CPU architectures that android systems use such as `arm64-v8a`, `armeabi-v7a`, `armeabi`, `x86_64` and `x86`. Is there a way for `adb` or any other tool to detect the architecture of a connected device? I have many devices connected to a PC running adb and I would like to create a script so that `adb` can deliver the correct package.

For example, I have packages `app_arm64-v8a.apk`, `app_armeabi-v7a.apk` and `app_armeabi.apk` on my desktop that correspond to their respective architectures as well as tens of android devices that are connected to an `adb` server on desktop. How can I iterate the output of `adb devices` so that the script figures out the architecture of each android device and automatically install the right apk to each device?

Comment: See: [How to find ARM processor version on android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6630386/295004)

Comment: [An answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/168320/44325) on [How to tell what architecture an APK is intended for?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/168302/44325) also briefly touched the ADB/shell command to detect the CPU/ABI list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell what architecture an APK is intended for?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/168302/how-to-tell-what-architecture-an-apk-is-intended-for)